# Нужна помошь в разработке алгоритма хранения данных

Tags: c++, алгоритм, хранение-данных

Привет! Есть простая задача(которую я не могу выполнить), которая заключается вот в чём: Создать следующий алгоритм:

- Пользователь выбирает элемент из списка, элемент(char*) передаётся в функцию.
- Пользователю предлагается ввести 2 дополнительных поля данных
- Когда пользователь снова выбирает этот элемент списка, ему уже предлагаются ранее введённые им доп.данные.

Примерный код(при первом повторном выборе того же элемента, дополнительные данные нормально отображаются, но при последующих выборах того же самого элемента(если не менять доп.данные, то есть один раз их ввести и дальше пропускать), выводится мусор(или пусто, но if всё равно возращает true)

```
map<char*,char*>data1;
map<char*,char*>data2;

 void data(char *in)
 {
 if(data1[in])
 cout<<data1[in];
 if(data2[in])
 cout<<data2[in];
 /*
Здесь вводим данные и записываем в data1, data2.
Также здесь есть возможность пропустить ввод, тогда в data1,  data2  ничего не записывается
*/
 }

 void choose(int n)
 {
  //здесь стоит switch с разными аргументами в вызове data()
  if(n==1)
  data("blabla");
 }

int main()
{
 for(;;)
 {
 int n;
 cin>>n;
 choose(n);
 }
 return 0;
}
```

Может подскажите какой-нибудь другой алгоритм?

Comment: Мне кажется нужно использовать `string` вместо `char*`

Comment: @diraria, уже написал другой алгоритм, спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Уже написал другой алгоритм, так что вопрос закрыт

### Алгоритм:

1. Пользователь выбирает элемент списка
2. Вызывается `Finish()`
3. Проверяется, не вводились ли доп.данные
4. Пользователь вводит доп.данные с/без подсказок
5. Goto 1;

### Код:

**Структура для буфферизации данных:**

```
class data_buff
{
char identifier[100];
char data1[100];
char data2[100];

data_buff()
{
//ну тут, короче обнуляем всё
};

};

data_buff *d_b[100];
```

**Ввод первых доп.данных(первый аргумент - выбранный эл.списка, второй - строка с этими самыми доп.данными)**

```
void Data1(char *identifier,char *data)
{
for(int i(0);i<100;i++)
if(d_b[i])
{
if(!strcmp(d_b[i]->identifier, identifier)
strcpy(d_b[i]->data1,data);
}
else
  break;
```

**Для data2 всё аналогично.**
**И завершение:**

```
void Finish(char *identifier)
{
int count=0;
for(int i(0);i<100;i++)
if(d_b[i])
if(!strcmp(d_b[i]->identifier, identifier)
{
count=i;
break;
}
else
{
d_b[i]=new data_buff;
strcpy(d_b[i]->identifier, identifier);
count=i;
break;
}

//Перед тем как создать поля, определим переменные, в которых будут хранится доп.данные

char data1[100]={}, data2[100]={};

//Инициализуруем

if(d_b[count]->data1)
strcpy(data1, d_b[count]->data1); //для 2 тоже самое

//Создаём поля для ввода, с подсказками, если они есть

}
```

Comment: Отлично! В идеале можешь описать алгоритм словами или даже добавить в ответ код своего алгоритма. (Тут так принято)

Comment: @diraria, знаю, но как-то лень¬_¬ Ладно, напишу